# Prophet: disable or hide verbose logger output

Tags: python, logging, facebook-prophet

Using ~~facebook~~ meta prophet's cross-validation function, I get lots of this:

`WARNING:prophet.models:Optimization terminated abnormally. Falling back to Newton.`

I can disable the stan output using [this](https://github.com/facebook/prophet/issues/223#issuecomment-310497971), but I can't seem to get rid of these pesky logs.  I might find them useful if I was running this interactively, but I'm not.

I'm already doing this near the top of my script:

```
import logging
logging.getLogger('fbprophet').setLevel(logging.ERROR)
```

It doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

You should ensure the qualifier is already set by te library, importing it.

> import fbprophet

after that, you can get the logger and disable it.

> logging.getLogger('fbprophet').disabled = True

I don't know if prophet use propagation to sub-qualifier, if so you can disable it by (use this technique carefully, disabling propagation can cause unwanted blinding situations):

> logger.propagate = False